# How to specify a CA for Courier POP3s?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, courier

We have our own CA that signed this certificate. Our CA's public cert is in /etc/ssl/certs on the server. It appears that Courier is not trusting or finding the CA cert?

I've added the CA to /usr/share/ca-certificates/ and ran ~sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates~, adding it to the client. No change.

This is my conversation with Courier from a remote client:

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.mycompany.com:995
```

```
+OK Hello there.
USER me@mycompany.com
+OK Password required.
PASS 12345
+OK logged in.
LIST
+OK POP3 clients that break here, they violate STD53.
.
RETR
RENEGOTIATING
depth=0 /C=US/ST=State/L=My City/O=mycompany, Inc/OU=Mail Server/CN=mail.mycompany.com/emailAddress=me@mycompany.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=US/ST=State/L=My City/O=mycompany, Inc/OU=Mail Server/CN=mail.mycompany.com/emailAddress=me@mycompany.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=US/ST=State/L=My City/O=mycompany, Inc/OU=Mail Server/CN=mail.mycompany.com/emailAddress=me@mycompany.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

How do I make Courier use the cert? Or is this a client issue?

**Update**:
Adding the CAs Public Cert in the .pem file (mail server key + mail server cert + ca cert) removes the previos errors, and replaces it with:

```
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I don't know if that's a step in the right direction or not. My understanding is that a CA's public cert is a self-signed cert, but how to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a client issue.

```
c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs/
openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -connect mail.mycompany.com:995
```

or:

```
openssl s_client -CAfile /path/to/rootca.pem -connect mail.mycompany.com:995
```